# PHP MongoDb insert deletes all old record

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I am inserting multiple records from a csv file into mongodb.

The records are inserted but whenever I am running the script, all the **previous records gets deleted** and only the new records are left

```
$connection=  new \MongoClient();
$db = $connection->selectDB('mydb');
$collection =  $db->selectCollection('users');

while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 0, ",")) !==FALSE) {
 try{ 
        $userData['_id'] =  new \MongoId();
        $userData['name'] = $data['0'];
        $userData['email'] = $data['1'];
        $userData['extra_info'] = $data['2'];


        $collection->insert($userData);
    }catch(MongoCursorException $e){
        // This is where I caught the duplicate id
        print_r($e->doc['err']);

        // Kill the procedure
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does $collection and $parsedData came from?

Comment: May you also post wich PHP Version and wich MongoDB-Version?

Answer (score 0):

You are using **insert**, please use **update method** for reserving previous records too...

To Update :

MongoDB's update() and save() methods are used to update document into a collection. The update() method updates the values in the existing document while the save() method replaces the existing document with the document passed in save() method.

**Syntax**

```
db.COLLECTION_NAME.update(SELECTION_CRITERIA, UPDATED_DATA)
```

That's all